# Obtain path of jar when running inside a .app on mac os x

Tags: macos, javafx, .app, java.library.path

I've my javafx jar running inside a .app. Now if I execute
 `System.getProperty("user.dir")`
 I get location of user home i.e. /Users/DevAccount/ where DevAccount is system user name instead of location of .app file or .jar file.
  How do I find where the .app is actually running from at runtime?

Alternatively please suggest how to set java.library.path to a folder within a .app bundle.

**Note:** If I run jar outside .app I'm able to set java.library.path as desired but when .app is run, user.dir system property does not return desired value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually javafxpackager by default sets java.library.path to .app/Contents/Java

So System.getProperty("java.library.path") itself can give the required path.

P.S.: @SO Admins, Surprised to see lack of response for most of my questions. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you give me idea to solve my issue :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36639175/derby-appdata-not-found-by-desktopos-jar-when-im-try-to-create-a-mac-os-x-appl