# Derby embedded database 'APPDATA' folder not found, Trying to create OS X application .app

Tags: java, macos, jdbc, derby, .app

I am trying to create a Mac OS X application from java desktopos.jar, where my application .jar file using derby embedded database APPDATA. It creates problem when, I'm createing a Mac OS X application .app

Here is my connection method on java(Already working on .exe and setup-Windows & Linux)

```
public static Connection getdataconnet() {
        Connection connect = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
            connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:APPDATA", "xxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
         } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            globalData.GlobalDataSetGet.OLD_USER = -1;
            ////JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "1"+ex);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            globalData.GlobalDataSetGet.OLD_USER = -1;
            ////JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "2"+ex);
        }
        return connect;
    }
```

**Mac OS X application architecture .app**
[image]

**APPDATA not found by .jar after creating a Mac OS X application .app**
[image]

Using CWD..

```
Connection connect = null;
    Path currentRelativePath = Paths.get("");
    String s = currentRelativePath.toAbsolutePath().toString();
    try {//DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:"+System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/APPDATA", "#####", "#############");
       connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:"+s+"/APPDATA", "#####", "#############");

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        globalData.GlobalDataSetGet.OLD_USER = -1;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "1"+ex);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        globalData.GlobalDataSetGet.OLD_USER = -1;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "2"+ex);
    }
```

[image]
Need dev help,Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JDBC Connection URL `jdbc:derby:APPDATA` says to look for the folder named APPDATA in the current working directory (CWD) of your application.

You need to figure out what your CWD is when your app is launched, perhaps by looking at the answers to this question: [Getting the Current Working Directory in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4871051/193453)

Then either

1. arrange to make your CWD be the place where APPDATA is stored, or
2. allow the user to tell your app where APPDATA is stored and put that in your JDBC Connection URL.

Comment: Connection connect = null;
        Path currentRelativePath = Paths.get("");
        String s = currentRelativePath.toAbsolutePath().toString();
        try {
            Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
           connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:"+s+"/APPDATA", "xxx", "lxxxxx");
 
        }//I'm using this CWD, But still not working..

Comment: Dear sir, Its good idea to define dynamic CWD But It still create problem when I'm trying to access my 'abc.app'.

Comment: Right before that `DriverManager.getConnection` call, print out "s", as in: `System.out.println(s);`. Then look to see if that string actually points to the folder where APPDATA is stored. If not, it needs to.

Comment: But .app show me '/' only the path becomes jdbc:derby://APPDATA

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21407315/2115117),
In Mac OSX app, location of current working directory of jar can be obtained using

```
System.getProperty("java.library.path")
```

Therefore, for connection string, use:

```
String pwd = System.getProperty("java.library.path");
connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:"+pwd+"/APPDATA", "#####", "#############");
```

Since I don't have access to Mac right now, just verify whether value of pwd ends with '/'. If yes append "APPDATA" instead of "/APPDATA".
Hope this helps!